# How to access Visual Studio activity log messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows

I want to access visual studio activity log during a running of a project till a failure occurs. Please tell me how do i access the log in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write output to the Debug console:

```
Debug.WriteLine("This is an output");
```

If you need a more sophisticated solution (e.g.: writing logs to the isolated storage) then you will have to implement that on your own. But there are already code samples where you can copy from, like this one:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-logging-solution-for-c407d880

Comment: I dont want to write to the debug console, i want to access all the debug messages. Is there any code for that. The sample you gave is not working in VS 2013.